# TypeError at /add_team/ 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
class AddTeamView(View):
    template_name = 'add_team.html'

    def get (self, request):
        form = TeamForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'add_team.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = Team()
            team.name = form.cleaned_data('name')
            team.details = form.cleaned_data('detials')
            context = {'form': form, 'team.name':team.name,'team.details':team.details}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

add_team.html :

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
add team
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="/add_team/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms


class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name of team')
    details = forms.CharField(label='details of team')
```

when I went to the browser it appeared this:

> TypeError at /add_team/ 'dict' object is not callable Request Method:
>   POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_team/ Django Version:
>   2.1.1 Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable Exception Location:
>   C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\teammanager\teams\views.py in post, line 52
>   Python Executable:
>   C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\teammanager_env\Scripts\python.exe Python
>   Version:
>   3.7.0

Comment: It is `form.cleaned_data['detials']` not `form.cleaned_data('detials')` (and probably you made a typo, `details` instead of `detials`).

Answer (score 2):

The `form.cleaned_data` is a dictionary, so you obtain elements by subscripting, or by using the `.get(..)` method (to return `None` or a default value in case the key is missing), so you should rewrite:

```
team.name = form.cleaned_data('name')
team.details = form.cleaned_data('detials')
```

to:

```
team.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
team.details = form.cleaned_data['details']  # typo: detials -> details
```

That being said, it is probably better to make a `ModelForm`:

```
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name of team')
    details = forms.CharField(label='details of team')
```

then the view looks like:

```
class AddTeamView(View):
    template_name = 'add_team.html'

    def get (self, request):
        form = TeamForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'add_team.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save()
            context = {'form': form, 'name':team.name,'details':team.details}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

You should also consider using a `CreateView`, instead of a simple view, and redirect when a `post(..)` is done successful, since rendering in case of a POST, can result in errors when the user refreshes the page (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern).

Answer (score 0):

after data in form is cleaning , new data is need to get which is post from another page.

Rewrite :

```py
team.name = form.cleaned_data('name')
team.details = form.cleaned_data('detials')
```

To :

```py
team.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
team.details = form.cleaned_data.get('detials')
```

Hope this Help!